# HTML Document Outlines: why is `<title>` not honoured?

Tags: html

Why is the element `<title>` not considered in the document outline? Surely this should be the root title? I’ve gotten into the habit of having a `<h1>` at the start of my page to include the page title in the document hierarchy, but surely this shouldn’t be necessary given we have `<title>`?

Answer (score 0):

`<title>` defines the title of the page as displayed in the browser window itself, not in the content of the page.  It should be between the `<head>` tags.

Comment: But why can't `<title>` be used as the root for the document hierarchy? It seems like it would be a perfect fit.

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted. You are asking about syntax of html and why it is a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

The `<title>` tag belongs in the `<header>` and describes the entire page. The `<h1>` tag describes a content block. You can have multiple `<h1>` tags on the page, but only one `<title>` tag should be present.

More on this can be found in the W3 HTML Specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/

To further add: the document outline describes rendered content, that is everything that goes in to the `<body>` tag. It is not required to use these additional tags, the `title` tag can be sufficient. However if the HTML page contains multiple articles/sections/documents then without these tags it will be hard for say a search engine to make sense out of the content.

Comment: But why can't `<title>` be used as the root for the document hierarchy? It seems like it would be a perfect fit.